# PropTypes oneOfType isRequired

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a component that expects propType oneOfType **bool** or **object** so I wrote:

```
processInfoValues: PropTypes.oneOfType([
   PropTypes.bool,
   PropTypes.object,
])
```

which is working fine, my problem is that this prop should be required, how can I achieve that?

I tried like that:

```
processInfoValues: PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  PropTypes.object.isRequired,
])
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
propType "processInfoValues" is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps declaration
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is happening because you are setting `isRequired` on the types inside of the `oneOfType`. You should set it on the outer PropTypes.
I think this might work

```
processInfoValues: PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.bool,
  PropTypes.object,
]).isRequired
```

Comment: Yes, it is! Thank you, I will accept your answer in 10 min (I cannot before that)